# How to use google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am new to JS and having challenges on resizing my google map.
 **My problem:** that only a third of my map is displaying and this is because a resize trigger needs to be implemented. 
**My question:** Where exactly do I correctly place the below trigger code within my script to implement it correctly.

Any help will be much appreciated

`google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`

> Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
/*use google maps api built-in mechanism to attach dom events*/
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {

  /*create map*/
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.506477,-0.071741),
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  /*create infowindow (which will be used by markers)*/
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  /*marker creater function (acts as a closure for html parameter)*/
  function createMarker(options, html) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
    if (html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(options.map, this);
      });
    }
    return marker;
  }

  /*add markers to map*/
  var marker0 = createMarker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.506477,-0.071741),
    map: map,
    icon: "../../account/gallery/1700728/images/marker-red.png"
  }, "<p>Saint Katharine's Way London E1W 1LD, United Kingdom</p>");
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#googleMap').css({'width':'100%','height':'380'});
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: your code as it works for me, triggering the resize-event at the current point is redundant. Is the map initially hidden(e.g. via `display:none`)?

Comment: no the map is not initially hidden, would you know how i can prevent triggering the resize-event from being redundant? any advise or help will be much appreciated

Comment: When `#googleMap` initially isn't hidden there is no need to trigger the resize-event. `window.load` fires **after** `document.ready` ,so when you create the map at a time when `#googlemap` already has the desired size as in your case  triggering the resize-event will not have any effect(at the current point `map` is still undefined, triggering of the resize-event is useless). As I said, you code works for me without the trigger:[**http://jsfiddle.net/s7trtdx3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7trtdx3/)  Please provide a demonstration of the issue,your code obviously isn't sufficient to give an answer.

Comment: do you want full screen rather than `'height':'380'` ..?